# Eigenvalue of the gradient of a vector valued function

Tags: c++, math, eigenvalue, calculus

How does the gradient of a vector(delta V) become a 3x3 matrix? And how do you compute its eigenvalue efficiently?  Is there any C++ library that can do this (can the C++ library Eigen do this)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector.  And yes eigen can compute eigenvalues of a matrix... so use it or another lib such as armadillo

Comment: Yes, I read that article. The gradient is a single row vector, how does it become 3x3? If I give Eigen a vector, can it turn it into a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: because you have different derivaties on 3 dimensions. And no you have to do render your matrix by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) is a generalization of the derivative for functions with more than one variable. It consists of all the partial derivatives of the function, so it has one derivative for each variable.

- For a **scalar valued** N-variable function `scalar y = f(x1, ..., xN)`, the gradient is a **vector with N scalar elements**.
- Generalizing it further to a **vector valued** function `vector y = f(x1, ..., xN)`, (where the vector has N elements, and the function has N scalar variables), the gradient can be thought as a **vector with N vector elements**, which is actually a matrix with NxN elements, also called the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

In your case the function must be like `vector3 y = f(x1, x2, x3)`, so the gradient is a 3x3 matrix.

You can compute the eigenvalues of it like for any other matrix, e.g. using [Eigen decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix). As the name suggests, the Eigen linear algebra library does offer such functionality.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that, in general, the matrix formed from the derivatives of an arbitrary vector field will not be symmetric. This means that the Eigen-decomposition of that matrix may involve complex numbers. If, on the other hand, the vector was itself the derivative of a scalar function, then the matrix of second derivatives would be symmetric and half real-valued eigenvalues.